# Magento 2: whenever I check product ids and filter grid and select other product ids at that time first selected ids get removed in grid serializer

Tags: magento2

```
$this->addColumn(
            'in_product',
            [
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'field_name' => 'in_product[]',
                'align' => 'center',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'filter_index' => 'entity_id',
                'values' => $this->getSelectedProducts(),
            ]
        );
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/o3bslc